# GUI not displaying all packets received

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I below is my code for receiving Multicast Wifi Data on android. I am using runnables like below to update the GUI but i found thatsome packets are missing. I am using this code to receive count down message but the count down is not continious. I dont know whether packets are lost due to the style of GUI updating or due to some other problem. request you all to give suggestions.

```
    package com.example.cdttiming;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        EditText time;
        String s;
        Button button;
     InetAddress ia = null;

         byte[] bmessage = new byte[1500];
         DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(bmessage, bmessage.length);
         MulticastSocket ms = null;
        @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

            time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_time);
        try 
            {
            WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
            //wm.setWifiEnabled(true);      
            WifiManager.MulticastLock multicastLock = wm.createMulticastLock("multicastLock");
            multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);        
            multicastLock.acquire();      

            ia = InetAddress.getByName("226.1.1.1");    
            try {
                ms = new MulticastSocket(4321);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            try {
                ms.joinGroup(ia);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            ms.setReuseAddress(true);


            }
               catch (UnknownHostException e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();

                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }     
         }

        public void startProgress(View view) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {

            while(true)
                {
                 try
                 {
                      ms.receive(dp);
              s = new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength()); 
                                         }
                 catch (UnknownHostException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                   catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }     


                   time.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        time.setText(s);

                    }
                  });
               }  // while
              }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
          }

        @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no access to main UI thread. That is why you can't set text to UI view element.

There are few methods to get access to UI thread
1) use Activity.runOnUiThread()

```
this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() { @Override
                    public void run() {
                        time.setText(s);

                    } })
```

2) I suppose best in your case use Handler object wich is a bridge between your worker threads and main UI thread

```
         private Handler handler = new Handler(){
                 @Override
                 public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                     switch (message.what) {
                         case SET_TEXT:{
                             time.setText(s);
                         }break;
     }
...
handler.sendEmptyMessage(SET_TEXT);
```

Comment: Hi Sergey Brazhnik can you please tell how should i implement this handler in my code .Actually i am a newbie in multithreading ,thats why i will request you to fit it into my code. Thanking you for your reply